# image in content body overlapping dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tweaked Bootstrap a bit (with a custom -theme.css file) to change the looks of the dropdown menu. I removed the borders from the navbar, wrapped a header around it which is set to be fixed on top (it didn't work with bootstraps in-house fixed-top navbar, can't remember why though).

It all works fine, only sometimes, things from the content body seem to overlap the dropdown menu, like seen in the picture below:

[image: Bootstrap shenanigans]

This is the code I'm using for the `<header>`-Tag around the navbar:

```
.site-header {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    height: 52px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading about how z-index actually works (as a webdesigner of over 10 years now... /facepalm), i tried adding a z-index to the `.site-header`-class. And it worked:

The code:

```
.site-header {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    height: 52px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The result:

[image: All cool!]

The thing is, that z-index only works for elements whose position property has been explicitly set to `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`